# is there a way to open "My Location" from Command Prompt for Windows Maps?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, bing-maps

Im trying to create a batch file that runs from the command line that opens Windows maps with my location to another specific location. Any suggestions on what this batch file should look like?

I tried this but it didn't work:

start ms-drive-to:?destination.name=Green Lake

[image: Command Prompt for My Location to Destination]

Answer (score 1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app

Try

`ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake`

There is also walk-to:

`ms-walk-to:?destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake`

[image: Example from Windows + Run]

To do this from a batch file try

`explorer "ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake"`

Which also works from the run prompt.

Comment: I tried that as well, I will not be able to know  the longitude and latitude only the address of my destination

Comment: Explain what you mean by didn't work exactly, perhaps the location specified is not able to be driven or walked to, try Manhattan or another land based location. Also you could first reverse geocode the addresss, I am not sure if the api will work but you would also be able to specify 0 for the lat and lng

Comment: When I enter that in the command prompt it goes to the map app that's it nothing is inserted. What do your command prompt look like?

Comment: I used the same command in the answer above `ms-drive-to:?destination.latitude=47.680504&destination.longitude=-122.328262&destination.name=Green Lake` and the picture is the result I get after a few seconds of loading

Comment: My result just opens the maps app that's all

Comment: Not sure why as it works on both machines I tried on, 1 PC and 1 Laptop

Comment: @DarkCoder2000, I just checked, it works as a batch file also, see the updated answer and don't forget to accept / upvote!

Comment: I'm not sure either

Comment: At least you know how to open it from a batch file now :)

Comment: That works thanks man! You think I can use destination.name for a address

Comment: Not 100% sure my friend, you will have to experiment and find out. Please don't forget to accept / upvote

Comment: Got u! Will do!

Comment: @user12954151 Did you figure this out? I have the same problem. I have only the address and not longitude and latitude. Using only destination.name (without destination.latitude and destination.longitude) just opens the app :-(